# VI select visual block cannot reach the end of line

Tags: vi

I was trying to select a block of code and do the word replacement inside that block.

(Trying to replace all the letter b in the second and third line with letter d)

However, I cannot reach the end of a few lines while selecting.

For example, I cannot select all the characters in the second and third line. Any idea how can I do it?  Images below shows how much I can select at most for the second and third line, cannot move the cursor further to the right.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using "v" (--VISUAL-- mode) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to :set virtualedit+=block

Answer (score 0):

1. place a cursor on first letter in row
2. press "v"
3. move cursor in right and bottom directions until selection is done